# is it possible to differentiate whether it is Land line call or mobile line call?

Tags: android, blackberry

I would like to know that if i get a call from blackberry / android devices ,is it possible to differentiate whether it is Land line call or mobile line call programmatically?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically, no - because of number mobility a number can be provisioned to a land line and then moved to a cell phone, and without even considering caller-id spoofing that is used a lot by commercial callers.

In some edge cases you can probably employ some heuristic - for example in Israel there is no number mobility between landlines and cellular and all cellular providers start with 5, so if you get a call from a number that starts with 05 (local area code prefix) or +9725 (international E164 prefix) then you know its a cellular.

More technically, you may be able to get a license agreement with all cellular providers that you are interested to support, so that you can call their HLR (home local registry) to check if the calling number is listed as a cellular subscriber (on each and every cellular provider you want to support), though I assume that will be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you can subscribe directly to this database maintained by Neustar, however it costs $1,185 annually: http://www.tcpacompliance.us/content/tcpa_faq.html. This will allow you to determine whether the number has been ported from a wireless to landline and vice-versa.