# How do I determine whether an incomming call is from a cellular phone or landline?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is it possible to differentiate whether it is Land line call or mobile line call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744838/is-it-possible-to-differentiate-whether-it-is-land-line-call-or-mobile-line-call)

I am using the TelephonyManager in order to get indication for incoming calls.

Is there a way I can determine whether the calling number is from a cellular phone or landline (fixed) phone?

Comment: Its not possible. see below link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744838/is-it-possible-to-differentiate-whether-it-is-land-line-call-or-mobile-line-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible. see below

[is it possible to differentiate whether it is Land line call or mobile line call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744838/is-it-possible-to-differentiate-whether-it-is-land-line-call-or-mobile-line-call)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can know that. That depends on national dial plan, may differ in each country. You may try to resolve number using DNS ENUM, but you would need network and even in that case, it would be unreliable.